# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "hinreichen" und nur "reichen"?

Tags: word-usage, difference

Ich bin kein Deutscher und ich kann nicht verstehen, was der Unterschied zwischen *hinreichen* und *reichen* ist. Vielleicht fehlt es mir nur an ein bisschen Hintergrundwissen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Reichen**

1. "Jemandem etwas geben". Man kann hier je nach Kontext auch *anreichen* (=helfend etwas reichen), aber auch *hinreichen* (=in Richtung von jemandem reichen) sagen. Beides ist aber weniger gängig.

   > Kannst du mir mal das Besteck *reichen*.
   >   Kannst du mir die Bücher *anreichen*/*hinreichen*. (Während man z. B. auf einer Leiter steht.)
2. "über eine große Fläche" hinweg sichtbar/verfügbar/bekannt/… sein.

   > So weit das Auge reicht. (=> so weit, wie man sehen kann)
   >   Meine To-do-Liste reicht von hier bis nach China. (figurativ: Die Liste ist so lang, dass sie den Platz von hier bis China benötigt)
3. "in großen Mengen verfügbar". Auch *ausreichen* und *hinreichen* möglich. Während *ausreichen* sehr gängig ist, wird *hinreichen* wiederum eher spärlich verwendet.

   > Mein Geld reicht nicht (aus). (=> zu wenig Geld)
   >   Solange der Vorrat reicht. (=> solange wie noch etwas da ist)

**Hinreichen**

1. Identisch zu Bedeutung (1) von *reichen*, mit einer leichten Implizierung, dass man jemandem etwas entgegen reicht, also zu jemandem hin. Beispiele siehe oben.
2. Identisch zu Bedeutung (3) von *reichen*. Beispiele siehe oben.

Somit sind zwei der drei Bedeutungen von *hinreichen* auch abgedeckt. Das Wort ist aber generell weniger gebräuchlich. In 99 % der Fälle sollte die Verwendung von *reichen* vollkommen ausreichen. Ich wage zu behaupten, es reicht *hinreichen* im passiven Wortschatz zu haben und zu verstehen, dass es im Wesentlichen das Gleiche wie *reichen* bedeutet.

Es gibt noch die beiden Adjektive *hinreichend* und *ausreichend*. Beide bedeuten im weitesten Sinne, dass von etwas genug da ist bzw. etwas angemessen vorhanden ist.

> Im Gebäude sind wir *hinreichend* gegen den Sturm geschützt.
>   Der Wasservorrat ist *ausreichend* für die nächsten Monate.

Comment: Könntest du "hinreichend" noch erwähnen?

Comment: Sicher doch. Ist meine Erweiterung hinreichend/ausreichend? ;)

Answer (score 6):

Erwähnenswert scheint mir noch die *hinreichende Bedingung*, ein Begriff aus der Logik und Mathematik. Während eine *notwendige Bedingung*

> für eine Aussage K eine Aussage, die zwingend wahr (erfüllt) sein muss, wenn K wahr ist.

ist, sorgt eine *hinreichende Bedingung*

> zwangsläufig für das Eintreten des bedingten Ereignisses.

(Quelle: [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notwendige_und_hinreichende_Bedingung), ich geb's zu)

Da das schon für Muttersprachler nicht einfach zu verstehen ist, hier noch die englischen Termini, die vielleicht eher weiterhelfen: *necessary* vs. *sufficient condition*.

Comment: Hmm, allerdings sehe ich keinen Unterschied zwischen einer *reichenden Bedingung* und einer *hinreichenden Bedingug,* außer dass letzterer Begriff halt der üblichere ist.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft "Hinreichende Bedingung" ist ein stehender Begriff (siehe z.B. http://didaktik.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/files/notwendig_und_hinreichend.pdf). In welchem Zusammenhang wird "reichend" als allein stehendes Adjektiv gebraucht, also nicht wie z.B. in "bis zum Horizont reichend"?

Comment: @MartinSchwehla: Dass das ein stehender Begriff ist, ist mir sehr wohl bewusst. Aber ich kann mir immer das Adjektiv *reichend* immer als Partizip aus *reichen* bilden und dann besteht hier kein Unterschied zu *hinreichend.*

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Grundsätzlich richtig, dass es *technisch* möglich ist - allerdings wird so ziemlich jeder deutsche Muttersprachler stutzen und entweder davon ausgehen, dass es sich um einen Fehler handelt, oder etwas Spezielles ausgedrückt werden soll, das nicht von "ausreichend" oder "hinreichend"abgedeckt wird. Gerade im vorliegenden fachsprachlichen Kontext problematisch. Theoretisch mag kein inhaltlicher Unterschied bestehen - in der Praxis funktioniert die Kommunikation im einen Fall wie beabsichtigt, im anderen nicht.

Answer (score 5):

"Hinreichen" hat drei Bedeutungen*):

1. jemandem etwas hinreichen, d.h. sich zu jemandem hinbewegen und ihm etwas geben

In dieser Bedeutung wurde "hinreichen" im modernen Sprachgebrauch weitgehend von "reichen" abgelöst:

> Ich reiche dir eine Flasche Mineralwasser (hin)

2. sich erstrecken, eine Ausdehnung bis zu einem bestimmten Punkt haben, bis zu dem man (hin)reicht:

> Die Wüste reichte hin bis zum Horizont.

Hat heute eine dichterische Färbung, in normaler Prosa würde man eher "reichte bis..." oder Ähnliches schreiben.

3. genügen für etwas, einen bestimmten Zweck, eine Absicht etc. im Sinn von "ausreichen", "gerade reichen". Die Konnotation ist eher negativ, da es um eine Einschränkung geht:

> Der Kredit reicht hin, um das Büro mit dem Nötigsten auszustatten.
>
> Seine Fähigkeiten reichten hin, um die Grillbude am Laufen zu halten.
>
> Seine Rente reichte nicht hin, um nach Spanien auf Urlaub zu fahren.

Heute würde man statt "hinreichen" eher "ausreichen" sagen. "Ausreichen" hat jedoch eine neutrale Konnotation:

> Seine Sprachkenntnisse reichten aus, um am Bahnhof ein Ticket zu kaufen.
>
> Ihre Erbschaft reichte aus, um ihr restliches Leben im Luxus zu verbringen.

4. Häufige Verwendung findet das Partizip Präsens "hinreichend". Es wird fast nur in einem abstrakteren Kontext eingesetzt:

> Es gab keinen hinreichenden Grund, ihn weiter festzuhalten.

aber eher ungewöhnlich:

```
Seine Rente war nicht hinreichend, um nach Spanien auf Urlaub zu fahren.
```

Dafür würde man eher sagen:

> Seine Rente reichte nicht (aus), um...

*) http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH09185