# Differences between "reichen," "ausreichen," and "hinreichen" and the idea of "enough"

Tags: difference

How do "reichen," "ausreichen," and "hinreichen" differ from one other? Duden provides very similar definitions for each. If you would like to provide other similar words as well, I'd appreciate that a lot.

I have a slight feeling that "reichen" means "to be enough," but specifically for things that can be "counted." (Think, cars in a parking lot, tables in a restaurant, etc.) In contrast, I'm guessing "hinreichen" and "ausreichen" denote things that are more continuous, or whose counting would almost-impossible. (Grains of sand on a beach, water in a lake, etc.) I'm not sure how "ausreichen" and "hinreichen" differ from each other, though.

Also, does the idea of what is "enough" factor into which form of "reichen" is used? Would these sentences take different forms of "reichen" (or different words altogether)?

"Only a few grains of sand are enough to scratch your cornea."

"The sand we have here (either in a bucket or in an area) is enough to build a sand castle"

"The team we have here is enough to participate in the game."

I found a related answer here ([Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "hinreichen" und nur "reichen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/20842/was-ist-der-unterschied-zwischen-hinreichen-und-nur-reichen)) but my german isn't nearly good enough to understand it fully, and my question is different in any case.

Answer (score 2):

## Preliminaries

*reichen* is a word with an iridescent conceptual core. The literal meaning of *reichen* is *to hand*, *to pass*, but also *to reach* and also *to spread*, *to span* in the sense of *to have a certain extension*. (*der Bereich* is *the area*.)

See the following sentence as an example for the concept of *reichen*:

> Der Baumstamm reicht über den Bach bis ans andere Ufer.
>
> The tree trunk reaches across the creek, right unto the other shore.

The meaning *to hand* and *to reach* have a common semantic core which is the "bow" between one point and the other. On the one hand, the "bow" is formed by the movement of the hand during giving, on the other hand, the "bow" is formed by the spanning thing which connects two things, reaching from one to the other. (Sorry for being so metaphorical myself, I hope you get what I mean.)

The meaning *to suffice* is a figurative extension of that meaning *to reach*, *to have an extension*. *reichen* in the figurative meaning *to suffice* and *reichen* in the literal meaning *to reach* share the concept of *to span*, *to stretch over* in the sense of *to cover*.

## Differentiation

### reichen

Your assumption concerning *reichen* is wrong: It is not the case, that *reichen* would be used exclusively for countable things. A very common use case of *reichen* is the fixed phrase *Es reicht!* (*It is enough!* in the sense of *It is too much now*).

### ausreichen

*ausreichen* can best be translated as *to suffice*, *to be sufficient*. That means, I'd say, it is relative to a certain purpose (which is not necessarily explicit, but at least implicit.). *reichen* can also be relative to an implied or explicit purpose, but I feel that with *ausreichen* the emphasis on that purpose is slightly stronger.

### hinreichen

*hinreichen* is nearly only used to form an adjective from its present participle *hinreichend*. You would never say *Das reicht völlig hin.*, but would always say *Das reicht völlig aus.* The use of *hinreichen* (as verb) is possible, but will always sound unidiomatic, I'd say. If its use would not be limited to this case, it would be more similar to *ausreichen* than to *reichen*.
In some fixed phrases, *hinreichend* is mandatory and could not be replaced without the loss of idiomacy. One of those fixed phrases is *hinreichende Bedingung* (*sufficient condition*) in logic.

### zureichen

To make your confusion even bigger, there is also the verb *zureichen* which means the same as *ausreichen*. Besides being used in dialect, it is used only used with the adjective from its present participle *zureichend* or the negated adjective *unzureichend* (*insufficient*), which differs from *hinreichend* by the fact, that *hinreichend* is not negatable (the word **unhinreichend* does not exist). In case it is not negated, *zureichend* is rarely used, instead *ausreichend* or *hinreichend* would be used.

### genügen

The verb *genügen* from the adjective *genug* (*enough*) also means *to suffice*. *genügen* differs from the other verbs by more positive associations: *genügsam* means *frugal*, *modest*, *humble*.

Maybe one can understand the slight difference between *genügen* and *reichen* best by an example. See the two sentences

> Es genügt mir.

in contrast to

> Es reicht mir.

While both could be translated as

> It is enough for me.

the first sentence has the subtext "I am happy with what I got", whereas the latter can also be meant sarcastically and has the subtext "I cannot stand it anymore, it is too much for me."

This association of *genügen* is not necessary, though. So, *genügen*, especially if negated, can simply mean *suffice*. The verbal paraphrase of mark 6 in school (the worst mark) is *ungenügend* (*insufficient*). Besides that, *genügen* generally has a higher tone. It can nearly always be replaced by *reichen*, but then the sentence would loose some high tone. I try to make an example again:

> Du genügst mir nicht.
>
> You don't suffice my demands.

.

> Du reichst mir nicht.
>
> You are not enough for me.

### langen

In Saxonian dialect, and maybe also elsewhere, we also have *langen* as a synonym for *reichen*. This is interesting in some sense, because *langen* echoes the conceptual metaphor of *reichen*: *langen* is etymologically related to the adjectiv *lang* (*long*), so it beares the concept of *stretching*, *spanning*, too. *jemandem eine langen* is colloquial for *to punch someone*. The underlying concept here is that you reach out your hand to punch the other person. *verlangen* means *to demand* or *to long*, the underlying concept is again the outstretched hand. *erlangen* also means *to gain*, *to reach*, again the outstretched hand is part of the concept.

The literal meaning of *langen* is also *to hand* and the figurative meaning of *langen* *to suffice* is similar to that of *reichen*.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: How does the adjective form of "zureichen" differ from "hinreichen," other than the fact that "zureichen" can be negated? Also, how does "genügen" differ from "ausreichen" and "reichen"? Is it relative to purpose, like "ausreichen"? When would you use it instead of the other two?

Comment: @Aaron I have extended my answer to make it contain my attempts to answer these questions as well.

Comment: Also compare *Genugtuung, Berreicherung, Verlangen*. To show that the metaphor around *langen* is not limited to Saxon, compare further judicial *erlangen* and *belangen* (do those come from Saxon law code, though?). *Jemandem eine langen* "to give someone a jab" is synonym with *eine einschenken, geben, ...*, thus compare *ergiebig*. Conversely, we have *auskommen, einkommen, bekommen, erhalten, aushalten, unterhalten, ...*.

Comment: Platt has *dat tut* "that works", which reminds of "will do". Where the root \*deh1- does have a connotation "do, put, place"; thus compare *da* "there, because", En *given that*.

Answer (score 0):

*hinreichen* is a formal term, known from Math *hinreichendes Kriterium* (opposed to notwendiges Kriterium), Law and Philosophy; Logic for short. Equivalently, *hinreichende Bedingung*

*ausreichen* and *reichen* are synonyms, but *ausreichen* is the specific term for *just about enough*.

---

I figure that *aus* means depletion, but it could also imply *further, away, towards a goal*. A relation to *reach out* would not be too surprising (if he reached out to me to help out), especially comparing *aushelfen*. On the other hand compare *extend* with Lt *teneo* (I am not sure how they relate to each other) and perhaps Ger. *strecken*, *recken*. Compare just En. *tend*. Cp *hang on* (in a sense keep it up?), *hang in*, *Hang* (slope), inclination ... the mental image of a tree is very fitting, as *rect-* and *reichen* have been compared (and height is obv a better image for a tree, even if it's layed down length wise). Perhaps also compare *reif* "ripe" for *es reicht* and *reich an Vitaminen*, *reif mit ...". *halten* "will it hold"; *Rechen* "rake" (thus I always thought *rechnen* means "to collect, sum up"); *Regen* "rain" (*Die Pflanzen sehen schlecht aus, werden Sie ausdauern bis zum Rechen* -- *g* can be fricative in dialect).

Another word in this sense is *dauern*, *überdauern*, *ausdauern* (related to *dry*, *trocken* if I am not mistaken), without the sense of consumption.